My login route layout still shows root layout components in nextjs 14?
I'm new in nextjs (App router).
In my root app/layout.tsx I have sidebar and header components which should be available for all other pages:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Sidebar from "@/app/components/sidebar";
import Header from "@/app/components/header";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Admin Dashboard",
  description: "Created by me",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <div className="flex min-h-screen bg-[#F9FAFB]">
          <Sidebar />
          <main className="flex-1 min-h-screen ml-1/5 p-4">
            <Header />
            {children}
          </main>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

it is  my login/layout.tsx
export default function LoginLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center bg-[#F9FAFB] w-full">
      <div className="w-full max-w-md p-6 bg-white rounded shadow-md">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

But when I go to login route, it still shows Header and Sidebar, which it shouldn't. My login component should be placed in plain background. How to fix it?

You can use Route Group feature of nextjs to handle layout for specific route groups.
You can go through Route Group documentation here


Whatever you place in the app/layout.tsx is available to every page inside your application. Layouts are nested as per folder heirarchy. If you don't want the login page to have it then put the main-layout file inside a folder, something like  app/home/layout.tsx and now everypage that has this layout will go inside the app/home route.
Your login page that do not have this layout will go inside app/login folder

Do not add anything in app/layout.tsx.
Instead, in your app/page.tsx:
export default function Home() {
    return (
        ...
        <Link href="/login">Log in</Link> // this will lead to your sign-in page
        ...
    );
}

You don't need a layout in your app/login/page.tsx either. Just create the UI for signing in. After a user signs in, redirect them to your Dashboard (or whatever page you want them to land on) by using:
In your app/login/page.tsx:
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Page() {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        ... 
        <button onClick={() => router.push("/dashboard")}>Sign In</button> 
        ... 
    );
}

This will bring a user to your Dashboard. Finally, you can add your sidebar and header to the dashboard layout in app/dashboard/layout.tsx.

I think you just want to show header and sidebar on all pages except login page. The simple solution is to render the component conditionally using "usePathname" hook of next.js.
Here is the example:
'use client'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
const pathname = usePathname()
const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
     if (pathname === "/login") {
         setShowSidebar(false)
     } else {
         setShowSidebar(true)
     }
}, [pathname])
return (
    <div>
      <div className='flex w-full'>
        {showSidebar && <Sidebar />}
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
   );
 }

export default Layout;

